# Algebra with fractions where variable is combined with a real number

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I am stumped. Here is the question. For all x in the domain of the function $\frac{x+1}{x^3-x}$, this function is equivalent to:

The correct answer is $\frac{1}{x^2-x}$

I just don't see for the life of me how that works. I would really be grateful for some help. This is question 38 on the 2008 ACT so its not even supposed to be that difficult.

Comment: Factorise the denominator.

Comment: $x^3-x=x(x^2-1)=x(x-1)(x+1)$. Then $\frac{x+1}{x^3-x}=\frac{x+1}{x(x-1)(x+1)}=\frac{1}{x(x-1)}=\frac{1}{x^2-x}$

Comment: Of course! Why didn't I see that? Thanks for both of you so much.

Answer (score 1):

Equate the equation to $y$ and manipulate the equation to bring $x$ in terms of $y$. Then you can easily find domain of $x$ which will be the same as the range of $y$.